# File not found with subdomain and php's system() function

Tags: php, path, subdomain

In a php script i want to check certain file types, which i do like this:

$info = explode('/',system("file -bi -- uploads/img/test.gif"));

if ( $info[0])
echo 'ok';

This is working just fine, as long as the url is without subdomain, f.e domain.com, but is not working under en.domain.com. It appears, that the file is just not found.

On the other hand, if in the same script i check for existance of the file:

if ( file_exists("uploads/img/test.gif"))
echo 'exists';

The file is found, wheter the current url is domain.com or en.domain.com. Why is the file not found, if the system() function is used?

solved

Friends, i finally figured out the solution, after nearly three working days. Maybe you can imagine how relieved i am.

the solution was in php options to activate mod_rewrite. this was allready activated in regular domain, but not for subdomains. guess i could have thought of this earlier. Even though your answers didnt lead me to how to solve this, i still thank you for your input, as it was going in the same directions i was trying to solve it myself the past days.

Comment: Are Both the images on the same server or different server? Also have you tried to use Absolute path like `/var/www/projectdir/uploads/img/test.gif`?

Comment: Yes i have tried that several times with /var/www/web0/projectdir/uploads/test.gif.

Comment: Have you also check the owner permission of the file?

Comment: I am using debian system and the owner is web0:web0. Also i chmoded test.gif to 777 still not working.

Answer (score 1):

The shell command will not necessarily take your file root to be the same as the php command (one will be the user's root directory and the other will be the webserver I think), use absolute path(s) in the shell command and this will probably work how you want it.

You could work out where the two url's are with the file command by using pwd, e.g.

```
echo system('pwd');
```

Or you could use [finfo-open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) instead of the shell command which should avoid the problem.

Comment: I just tried again, using an absolute path: $info = explode('/',system("file -bi -- /var/www/web0/html/projectdir/projectdir_home/uploads/img/test.gif")); - but still to no avail. I think you are right though, that this probably has something to do with system() beeing a shell command.

Comment: You can always try and use pwd to work out where you are with both url's with that file command then work from there.

Comment: Uhm, could you give an example?